# If I refresh the page when I'm logged in, the Guard redirects me to the login page

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angular-ui-router, auth-guard

If I refresh the page when I'm logged in, the Guard redirects me to the login page. Is there a way for redirecting to the login page only if the user truly log out?
I am using frontend as angular (version: 12.2.13)and backend as firebase.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    if(this.authService.isAuth()){
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your Guard code and import Guard  code

Comment: have you created any guard? if yes, then please share your code

Comment: what does `this.authService.isAuth()` return?

Answer (score 0):

When user logged in the application, user's status should be saved in sessionStorage or Redux.Then An AuthGuard service must be defined.Finally the AuthGuard must be added to each Routes.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    
    const userLoginStatus = sessionStorage.getItem("userLogin");
    const IsUserLogin: boolean | null = userLoginStatus ? JSON.parse(userLoginStatus) : null;
    
    if ( IsUserLogin ) {
      return true
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
      return false
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Routes with home route protected by AuthGuard**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

    // home route protected by auth guard
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**AuthGuard redirects to login page if user isn't logged in**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```